# How come my entire project is not pushed to Github?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-init

I am trying to push an ASP.NET 4.5 MVC 5 project onto Github. For some reason, whenever I do it, it acts like it isn't recursively going through the folders and doesn't push some of the project's sub files.

Here is the repo:
https://github.com/albatrosscafe/HeavyweightDocumentationV2

The repo has a couple of binary files and then one folder for "Packages" (different web libraries).
There should be an entire folder that contains the actual website content like the HTML, the server code, etc. but it doesn't seem to get pushed to the repo at all! I don't know why! I have tried committing from the git GUI and from the command line. It always says that there are 479 files to commit, and then when I push them, it is only pushing 249 files.

Any advice?

Comment: What does `git ls-tree -r master` say?

Comment: It looks like it lists all the files that are currently already on Github, but not the ones that still aren't being pushed.

Comment: The command I listed lists all the files that are checked in into git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I may have figured it out. I went into the sub directory that wasn't being published, did `git add *` and committed all of those from there, then navigated back to root and pushed. Now all of the files are up.

I believe then that this means there must be some kind of recursive option/argument that I forgot to toggle if you are calling git-push from the root.